# What does "Lots taken" mean?

Tags: meaning

I came across a TV show dialogue.

I couldn't find ***lots taken*** in any dictionaries. I guess it means I care and I was insulted but my Chinese subtitle means I don't care, it's okay.

***None taken*** is generally used to reply to ***No offense***. I believe ***None taken is an antonyms of Lots taken.*** Could you please correct me? Thanks.

```
**NO OFFENCE** - A phrase added to an otherwise insulting statement. 

You say "no offense" right before or after you say 
something that is insulting. 

"No offense" allows you to say just about anything you want about anyone.

It is sometimes followed up by "none taken." 

The recipient of the original comment says "none taken" 
to signal that they were not insulted.
```

**Context: Kelsey and Liza are friends. Thad is Kelsey's boyfriend. Josh is Liza's boyfriend**

> Kelsey: We're gonna see that guy that Liza's been seeing, Josh. We're
>   gonna go see Josh at his tattoo parlor in Brooklyn, and we're all
>   gonna get tattoos.
>
> Thad: Babe, you know I don't do Brooklyn. No offense.
>
> Liza: **Lots taken.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're right. "Lots taken" means that they **were** offended by the statement.

In your first example, you have:

> A: No offense.
>   
> B: None taken.

The "none taken" means "no offense was taken".

Similarly, in:

> A: No offense.
>   
> B: Lots taken.

Here, "lots taken" means "a lot of offense was taken"... so the rude comment was made and, despite A trying to play it off, B still took offense at the comment.

Though, in reality, this is likely said sarcastically, or as a joke. It would be unlikely for someone to use this if they were actually offended.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock You're totally right. I'd mentally told myself to add that in and failed.

Comment: Can I ask 1 more question? What does **you know I don't do Brooklyn** mean? I guess _I don't like Brooklyn_ . There is no result from google.

Comment: You should ask it as a new question. :)